# Tensorflow: import init_ops and random_ops

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to create a custom initializer based on the code of tf.truncated_normal_initializer.

However, when I try to import init_ops and random_ops. I get the error:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ops'`

to reproduce:

```
import tensorflow.python.ops.random_ops as random_ops
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, quite trivial. Issue solved with

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import random_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import init_ops
```